# Convert Func<T, TProperty> to Expression<Func<T, Property>>

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, repository-pattern

I've got a generic repository implementation that allows to pass a selector in order to declare the entities primary key property:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<TEntity, TKey>
    where TEntity : class 
{

    private readonly Func<TEntity, TKey> _keySelector;

    protected Func<TEntity, TKey> KeySelector {
        get {
            return _keySelector;
        }
    }

    protected RepositoryBase(Func<TEntity, TKey> selector) {
        _keySelector = selector;
    }

}
```

... which can be used like this:

```
public class UserRepository : RepositoryBase<User, Guid>
{
    public UserRepository()
        : base((user) => user.Id)
    {

    }
}
```

I have now implemented a *in memory repository* to do some unit tests where I'd like to generate a new identity for each entity that is getting persisted. In case the entity does not have public accessor for the key, I've created a extension method to set properties using reflection.

```
public static void SetProperty<T, TProperty>(this T instance, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> selector,
        TProperty newValue)
        where T : class
    {
        if (instance == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");
        if (selector == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");

        var propertyInfo = selector.GetMember() as PropertyInfo;
        if (propertyInfo == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        propertyInfo.SetValue(instance, newValue);
    }
```

My question is now: How can I use the **KeySelector** as an *expression* in order to set the primary key value? Is there a way to convert it? Or are there better ways to achieve what I'm trying?

Like so? Does that even make sense?:

```
protected override void AddItem(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

        var id = default(TKey);
        if (GetPrimaryKey(entity).Equals(default(TKey)))
        {
            id = _identifierGenerator.Generate();
            entity.SetProperty(x => GetPrimaryKey(x), id); // <----
        }

        _items[id] = entity;
    }
```

---

Some methods used above:

#### Method 'GetPrimaryKey'

```
public TKey GetPrimaryKey(TEntity entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

    return KeySelector(entity);
}
```

#### Method 'GetMember'

```
public static MemberInfo GetMember<T, TProperty>(this Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        var memberExp = RemoveUnary(expression.Body);

        return memberExp == null ? null : memberExp.Member;
    }
```

#### Method 'RemoveUnary'

```
    private static MemberExpression RemoveUnary(Expression toUnwrap)
    {
        var unwrap = toUnwrap as UnaryExpression;
        if (unwrap != null)
        {
            return unwrap.Operand as MemberExpression;
        }

        return toUnwrap as MemberExpression;
    }
```

Comment: You can go `Expression<Func<T, TProperty>>` to `Func<T, TProperty>` but you can't go the other way. Can you show the code of `GetPrimaryKey`, perhaps that can be modified to return a expression.

Comment: You can easily get an `Expression<Func<T, TProperty>>` by doing `x => func(x)`, but it won't work for any provider other than `EnumerableQuery`'s, so it's pretty much useless for anything you might want to do.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Sure thing, I've added it above.

Comment: @hvd Is there maybe a better approach to what I'm trying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, basically - not in any useful way. The solution seems simple though - change the type of your property instead:

```
private readonly Expression<Func<TEntity, TKey>> _keySelector;

protected Expression<Func<TEntity, TKey>> KeySelector {
    get {
        return _keySelector;
    }
}

protected RepositoryBase(Expression<Func<TEntity, TKey>> selector) {
    _keySelector = selector;
}
```

You can still use a lambda expression to initialize the property, and you can compile the expression tree to a delegate if you really need to.